# tickSubdivide not always working?

Tags: svg, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to use d3.js to produce a large amount of charts (200+). This is the code that, randomly on some of the charts produce three minor axis lines, no lines or one or two lines:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(5).tickSize(-height).tickSubdivide(3);
```

I don't see any regularity in the behaviour, it just randomly shows or not some of the minor lines.
Has anyone had the same experience with this?

Cannot show any image cause I have not enough reputation, hope the problem is understandable anyhow,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to this page with some axes examples http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3605124

Comment: Thank you, in the end I avoided using them, they really didn't behaved the way like in your link, will keep this bookmarked and study more next year when I will have the same problem.